# Why was the male a'dam created?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

What was the original purpose the male a'dam was created for?

Also, why does it have two bracelets as opposed to one for the female version?

Comment: tritely, for the same reason that every a'dam was made - by people who feared that those with power didn't have strong restraints on it. Except, for the Male a'dam, that was probably true!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The male a'dam also called Domination Bands

> were made during the Breaking and allow a woman or two women to control a man who can channel

.

> Prior to the Cleansing of saidin

,

> the Domination Bands were dangerous to use because they did not prevent
>   the man from going mad. They are also imperfect because, given time,
>   he will eventually be able to control the woman as well as she
>   controlling him.

As to why there are 2 bracelets on the male version;

> While saidin was tainted

,

> this had extremely
>   dangerous repercussions. Two women in the bracelets reduces this back
>   seepage, but it also makes it harder to control the male channeler.

(from the wot wikia [article](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Domination_Band))

As they were made during the breaking, then that seems to imply that they were made with the purpose of trying to stop or control the mad male Aes Sedai.

Comment: or to control saidin for specific purposes for which saidar isn't sufficient